# VS Code - Text Editor behaving like terminal on click

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Rather then acting like a word document (for lack of a better way of putting it)

When I am using VS code, when I click into a new html document for example, it behaves as if I am I am typing in the termainal.

[image: Screenshit of the issue]

[image]

This used to happen to me when I would copy/paste something into the document.
I checked my shortcuts and could not see anything, thought it might be a problem with an exentsion or vs code itself. Uninstalled vs code and all my extensions and it did resolve the problem but it is back now, but as I said only occurs when I click into another file.

Comment: what do you see that is terminal like

Comment: I have updated the body of the question and added a gif... hopefully will clarify the issue I am having

Comment: I see something moving, there is nothing wrong with my eyes but this is a font size that is unreadable. Looks like you type `aaaaaa` and then you get a few lines `Lorem ipsum`, please type the additional text as text

Comment: most likely you are in VIM mode, `dd` is delete current line

Comment: Thank you very much, VIM was the issue, disabling it solved the problem.

Apologies for the quality of the gif was drastically downgraded, when I created it was much clearer. Even when I zoomed the browser is woefully pixilated.